# Как сделать 404 страницу в codeignither

Tags: codeigniter

Всем привет, допустим есть ссылка

http://test.mimgas.kz/service/detail/4

Которая котрывается нормально, но если допустим

http://test.mimgas.kz/service/detail/444444

ТО она тоже открывается, просто с БД не нашли данные. А как сделать перенаправление на 404 страницу если данные пустые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вызвать функцию Show_404

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable')->result_array();
if(empty($query)) show_404();
```